# how to render a script in _Layut based on the url or based on the page that we are in

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am rather new to ASP.Net MVC. I am using ASP.Net MVC 5 and I have a _Layout that renders some scripts. I want to render the scripts based on weather I am in a certain page or the URL is a specific url. here is my code in _Layout and the scripts that I want to render:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/plugins/skinConfig")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually define a section in your layout page where you can scripts for specific pages (notice it is not required):

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

And then in the actual views where you want to include the specific scripts, you do:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="#"></script>
}
```

If you want to be more fine-grained with your control of when the scripts are rendered, you can do some magic in the controller action and set a value on the vies model (or viewbag) to indicate that scripts should be rendered and then just do:

```
@if(ViewBag.ShouldRenderScripts)
{
    <script src="#"></script>
}
```